# I need to convert a bunch of *pngs to *.mpg in linux/CENTOS. How can I do this?

Tags: conversion, video-conversion, png, mpeg, mpg

Title says it all, and I am not too familiar with LINUX, but I can get by if I get some help.

I am looking for a way(s) where I can do the above, or in lieu of that, download a program that will do this for me. Very simply, I have a bunch of *.png 's that I would like to convert into a movie, (mpg, mpeg, mpeg2, whatever).

I have tried googling for any such softwares but I am getting some dubious websites and even more dubious programs.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, ffmpeg was quite good at this, and is availble for Linux as well.
The first thing that you have to do is to name all your files in a similar matter to this:

`01img.png, 02img.png, 03img.png, ..., 20img.png`

Now you only have to enter this in the terminal:

`ffmpeg -qscale 5 -r 20 -b 9600 -i img%02d.png movie.mp4`

Where the number after the '-r' flag is your framerate (fps).

Hope I helped.